# Resources$NotFoundException when i setText on textView an int value

Tags: android

when i logd good.getprice() it return an int but below code not working

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull goodsViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Good good = goods.get(position);
            holder.txtviewPrice.setText(good.getPrice());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use this implementation of `setText()`:

```
public final void setText(@StringRes int resid)
```

so a resource id is expected.  
but you want the number to be displayed as string so change to this:

```
holder.txtviewPrice.setText("" + good.getPrice());
```

or

```
holder.txtviewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(good.getPrice()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setText(String.valueOf(good.getPrice()))` instead.

setText(int i) expects resource ID, not int value to display.